# New home, do vanity lights require electrical boxes to be wired in?

Tags: electrical

I Opened an existing light fixture that came with house and there is no electrical box to install a new lights.

Builder is telling me it does not need an electrical box like other fixtures in the house. Does it require an electrical box to be mounted on ?

Does the electrical code require it to have one or not?

[image]

Comment: Is there a metal back to the fixture ? Some fixtures do not need a separate box this is true but the entry for the wire will need a clamp and the wiring will need to be enclosed, I asked about metal but it could also be plastic. A photo would help , but it is possible that fixture doesn’t need a box.

Comment: We need to know what the fixture is that you want to install and what the space looks like that you "opened" up.

Comment: Thanks for the photo of the wall, now we need to know what fixture you want to install.

Comment: Is there a box built into the fixture?